# How to Fetch data form firebase to fragments in Recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

**Java**
Here is the code of fragment of my app and when I run it my app crashes as soon as I start the app got Customer home fragment  it crashes, In logcat its showing there is  error in CustomerHomefragemnt so here's the code as I am not being able to troubleshoot it Please answer if someone can help. Here is my fragment code`

````
    public class CustomerHomeFragment extends Fragment implements 
    SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<UpdateDishModel> updateDishModelList;
    private CustomerHomeAdapter adapter;
    String State, City, Sub;
    DatabaseReference dataaa, databaseReference;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    SearchView searchView;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
    @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customerhome, null);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recycle_menu);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.move);
        recyclerView.startAnimation(animation);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        updateDishModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimaryDark, R.color.green);


        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                String userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                dataaa = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                           .getReference("Customer").child(userid);
                dataaa.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Customer cust = dataSnapshot.getValue(Customer.class);
                        State = cust.getState();
                        City = cust.getCity();
                        Sub = cust.getSuburban();
                        customermenu();
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        customermenu();
    }

    private void customermenu() {

        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FoodSupplyDetails")
          .child(State).child(City).child(Sub);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                updateDishModelList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        UpdateDishModel updateDishModel = 
    snapshot1.getValue(UpdateDishModel.class);
                        updateDishModelList.add(updateDishModel);
                    }
                }
                adapter = new CustomerHomeAdapter(getContext(), updateDishModelList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                search(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
    


    private void search(final String searchtext) {

        ArrayList<UpdateDishModel> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
        for (UpdateDishModel object : updateDishModelList) {
            if (object.getDishes().toLowerCase().contains(searchtext.toLowerCase())) {
                mylist.add(object);
            }
        }
        adapter = new CustomerHomeAdapter(getContext(), mylist);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.Searchdish);
        searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Dish");


      }
    }
```


`here is my Homeadapter code`



    public class CustomerHomeAdapter extends  
             RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerHomeAdapter.ViewHolder>
    {


    private Context mcontext;
    private List<UpdateDishModel>updateDishModellist;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    public CustomerHomeAdapter(Context context,List<UpdateDishModel>updateDishModellist)
    {
        this.updateDishModellist=updateDishModellist;
        this.mcontext=context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= 
            LayoutInflater.from(mcontext)
                 .inflate(R.layout.customer_menudish,parent,false);
        return new CustomerHomeAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final UpdateDishModel updateDishModel=updateDishModellist.get(position);
        Glide.with(mcontext).load(updateDishModel.getImageURL()).into(holder.imageView);
        holder.Dishname.setText(updateDishModel.getDishes());
        updateDishModel.getRandomUID();
        updateDishModel.getChefId();
        holder.price.setText("Price: ₹ " + updateDishModel.getPrice());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(mcontext,OrderDish.class);
                intent.putExtra("FoodMenu",updateDishModel.getRandomUID());
                intent.putExtra("ChefId",updateDishModel.getChefId());


                mcontext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return updateDishModellist.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView Dishname,price;
        ElegantNumberButton additem;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);
            Dishname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.dishname);
            price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.dishprice);
            additem=itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_btn);


        }
    }
   }
````

I think error is in this  code as i am not able to trouble shoot is please help me with this

```
private void customermenu() {
    
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    
            DatabaseReference databaseReference = 
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FoodSupplyDetails")
              .child(State).child(City).child(Sub);
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    updateDishModelList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            UpdateDishModel updateDishModel = 
        snapshot1.getValue(UpdateDishModel.class);
                            updateDishModelList.add(updateDishModel);
                        }
                    }
                    adapter = new CustomerHomeAdapter(getContext(), updateDishModelList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6075.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xndik.png)

Comment: what's the error you're getting ?

Comment: My app is crashing when I am  moving  to customerhomefragment activity. I think there is some issue  while fetching data form firebase I have attached Image link that defines that error is in private void method of customerhomefragment. Help me  if you can please it will be great

Answer (score 0):

From your code, your issue seems to be on below line:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FoodSupplyDetails")
              .child(State).child(City).child(Sub);
```

Error tells you you cannot pass null for ".child()". So it is telling you the values for State, City and Sub are null. You can confirm this by going to your Firebase's console database and seeing the data structure for the corresponding "Customer" with the firebase id.

Please check your Firebase database and make sure the customer data exists.

Comment: I have attached both screenshot of  customer and  fooddetails roots form firebase base you can refer that there data exists but it is not  being fetch please help me with this

Comment: What is the value of Sub? I don't see it in customer. No suburban shows. Do a quick test by adding Sub and value key pairs into your Customer and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run your query you should make sure the values are not null.

```js
if (State != null && City != null && Sub != null) {
  // Run your query here
} else {
  Log.d("TAG", "Data provided is null")
}
```

When you are fetching customer's information, try logging that and check which of them is null:

```java
String State, City, Sub;
//...

State = cust.getState();
City = cust.getCity();
Sub = cust.getSuburban();

Log.d("TAG", State);
Log.d("TAG", City);
Log.d("TAG", Sub);

// call customermenu now
customermenu();
```

Comment: hey its showing data provided is null so how can I fetch that from firebase whats wrong in  my code??

Comment: @VaibhavKale where does it log null? After fetching from database or inside customer menu function ?

Comment: No nothing  is being fetch in my activity but app just stop crashing so how  should I  fetch it?? I am beginner in  this field please help me with this.

Comment: I have joined your discord. How and in which room should we talk about??

Answer (score -1):

The error tells you you cannot pass null for ".child()". So it is telling you the values for data(stored in the firebase database) are null. You can confirm this by going to your Firebase's console database and seeing the data structure corresponding with the firebase id.